# Run .NET in vscode

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-code

When I click on `ctrl + alt + n` in vscode to run the C# code, the encoding constantly flies and the output gives me this

```
[Running] scriptcs "d:\Code\main.cs"
"scriptcs" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.382 seconds
```

the code itself is the usual "hello world"

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Before that, I downloaded the `Run code` and `C#` extensions from Microsoft

Comment: Do you have .net framework installed?

Comment: yes, v4.0.30319 installed

Comment: You need to set the VS encoding to match the encoding in your culture. See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e82947f5-f974-4579-aec2-65c3ee8d01be/how-to-change-text-encoding-on-an-output-window-for-visual-studio-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 1):

After `Console.WriteLine("Hello World")`

just add   `Console.ReadKey()`